# Trying to Find the Name of a Musical

Tags: identify-this-song, live-music

I'm hoping on a long shot somebody may know what I'm talking about. I'll definitely add more details if I can recall any.

- This is a sarcastic sort of musical, relatively new (within the last 10-15 years I'm almost certain, but say 20 to be extra safe).
- I seem to recall someone having gotten cancer in it (possibly something else bad, but cancer sticks out), and that there was a kid (almost positively a girl) with a lot of teenage angst. And that I believe the show revolved around a family including the teenage and the one who got cancer(?) (could easily be one and the same person).
- The soundtrack of this was shown to me about five years ago by a girl who was in her late teens (graduating high school) at the time. This is just a shot in the dark, but it may be something relevant to that age group, or at that time. Unfortunately I am no longer in touch with her, and cannot ask her.

Comment: http://www.breastinshow.org/ ? The only one I could find concerning cancer...

Comment: A valiant effort, but sadly not the one I'm thinking of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it, it was the musical: Next to Normal.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next_to_Normal

And for the record it wasn't cancer, it was a wife with bipolar disorder.

Comment: Link to site/video/something about it? As it stands it really leaves the answer a bit… limp.